# updating with frequency for customer ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, frequency

I have a table as shown below:

```
cust_id/frequency
01/null
01/null
02/null
02/null
01/null
03/null
04/null
04/null
03/null
```

after updates the table with the frequency, it should shown as below

```
cust_id/frequency
01/3
01/3
02/2
02/2
01/3
03/2
04/2
04/2
03/2
```

I have tried the below query, but it only shows the result I want, not updating the table.

```
select cust_id, count(*) as frequency
from table A 
group by cust_id 
order by count(*) desc
```

Is there any query to help me to update that as I have 10000 plus cust_id?

Thank you very much for spending your time to look at my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET    t1.frequency = cnt 
FROM   tbl t1 
       JOIN (SELECT cust_id, 
                    Count(1) cnt 
             FROM   tbl 
             GROUP  BY cust_id) t2 
         ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a very nice feature, which is that CTEs (and subqueries) can be updatable.  You can do what you want using updatable CTEs and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, count(*) over (partition by cust_id) as newfrequency
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set frequency = newfrequency;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    cust_id CHAR(2),
    frequency INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (cust_id)
VALUES 
    ('01'), ('01'), ('02'), ('02'),( '01'),
    ('03'), ('04'), ('04'), ('03')

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT cust_id, cnt = COUNT(1) 
    FROM @temp
    GROUP BY cust_id
)
UPDATE @temp
SET frequency = cnt
FROM cte
WHERE cte.cust_id = [@temp].cust_id

SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Output -

```
cust_id frequency
------- -----------
01      3
01      3
02      2
02      2
01      3
03      2
04      2
04      2
03      2
```